# Instantiate a Class annotated with some annotation

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I want to get information about *fields* from a Class on which a specific annotation is present by getting the annotation in annotation processor.

I can retrieve fully qualified class name from annotation but can't instantiate it, a `ClassNotFoundException` is being thrown, although class is there.

How can I check if class is not in class path or which classpath is included for annotation processor?

```
try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(((TypeElement) e).getQualifiedName().toString());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                cnfe.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: what path does `toString()` returns?

Comment: It returns class path for a class in my Android Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do in the code in the question is impossible because annotation processing occurs before the program is fully-compiled. That's why you work with e.g. `TypeElement` objects instead of `Class`, because the class is not-yet compiled.

On the other hand, if you just want to examine what sorts of fields are present, [you can use the `Element` API for that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getEnclosedElements--), for example:

```
for (Element e : typeElement.getEnclosedElements()) {
    if (e.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD) {
        VariableElement field = (VariableElement) e;
        //
    }
}
```